# Difference between Homogeneous first order operator and Homogeneous first order differential operator

Tags: smooth-manifolds, sheaf-theory, global-analysis

By definition, a **Homogeneous first order operator** on the algebra of differentiable functions is an operator like $$ Df = \sum \phi_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} $$ where $\phi_i$ are differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R^n}$ or open subset of  $\mathbb{R^n}$ , satisfying the **Leibniz rule**.

And we define **Homogeneous first order differential operator** as a sheaf homomorphism from $\mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A} $ , ($\mathcal{A(M)}$ is a sheaf on a differentiable manifold $M$).

Now, I suppose any homogeneous first order operator can be defined as a sheaf homomorphism from $\mathcal{A}$ into itself satisfying Leibniz rule. So what is the difference between above defined two operators? What is the **differential** structure defined on the second operator that makes it different from the first one?